# R function doesn't pass on content of string variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to run many Cox Regression Models, so I define the following function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(finalfit)
runcox <- function(df,dependent,exp_full,label_name="placeholder"){
  coxdata <- df %>%
    finalfit(dependent, 
             exp_full,
             exp_reduced,
             add_dependent_label = FALSE,
             keep_models = TRUE) %>%
    rename(label_name = label) %>% 
    rename(" " = levels) %>%
    rename("  " = all) 
  
  return(coxdata)
}
```

now calling on the function

```
runcox(data,dependent,explanatory,"Overall Survival")
```

works, but the label of the cox model remains `"placeholder"` instead of adjusting the label to the content of the passed variable `label_name="Overall Survival"`.

Changing `rename(label_name = label)` to `rename("Overall Survival" = label)` also works, but it want this to be a variable I can pass to the function.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try: `rename(!!label_name := label)` or `rename({{ label_name }} := label)`.

Comment: ```rename(!!label_name := label)``` does indeed work. Thanks. Can you repost as an answer so I can mark it? It would be great if you could briefly explain what ```rename(!!label_name := label)``` does

Comment: @spx31: When I use your function on the iris data, it is not working at all. Can you post an reproducible example?

Comment: Q: Why does `rename(!!label_name := label)` work? A:  [NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).  There is an important difference between a character string containing the name of an R object and the R object itself.  Consider the difference between `print("iris")` and `print(iris)`.